# Can the pole of a analytic function be of rational order

Tags: complex-analysis

Can a pole of an analytic function have a rational number as its order?

Answer (score 10):

No. Isolated singularities of analytic functions are either removable, poles (of integer order) or essential.

You may wonder: what about $1/\sqrt{z}\,$? Could not we say that $z=0$ is a pole of order $1/2$? No, because $z=0$ is not an isolated singularity of $f$; it is a *branching point*. It is impossible to define $1/\sqrt{z}$ in such a way that it is analytic in a punctured neighbourhood of $z=0$.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, $1/z$ is not analytic in any neighbourhood of $0$ either. Perhaps you mean a punctured disc?

Comment: @Zhen Lin Yes, of course.

Comment: Sir, Mr. julian aguirre, as u have mentioned that poles can have integer order. i think that the order of pole can be positive integer only. if it will be of negative order then it will turn into zero of the function. Am i right sir?

Comment: Yes of course, I meant positive integer.

Comment: Please explain 'punctured' neighbourhood.

Comment: A punctured neighbourhood of $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ is a neighbourhood of $z_0$ with the point $z_0$ deleted, like $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z-z_0|<r\}$ for any $r>0$.